# Twig - add attribut to curent element

Tags: symfony, if-statement, attributes, twig

I'm using Symfony2 Framework with twig to generate my template.

I'm trying to show differents images in a carousel (plugging Jquery) and I put an image zoom (other plugin jquery) on each images.

I'm generating my image from a yaml file.

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    {% for datas, values in values['themes'] if datas == category %}
        {% for value, key in values %}
            <li>

                <img src="{{ asset(key.urllow) }}" class="photo-diapo" id="{{ value }}" data-zoom-image="{{ asset(key.url) }}"/>

                <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>

                <h3 class="photo-titre">{{ key.titre }}</h3>
                <h4 class="photo-date">{{ key.date }}</h4>
                <p class="photo-description">{{ key.description }}</p>

            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My question is for the image attribut data-zoom-image.
Is there a way to add this attribut with twig only if the image is the curent image on screen ?

Like a {% if ... %} data-zoom-image {% endif %} with a special condition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use Twig's loop variable, as described in [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable). In your case, the template will look pretty much like this:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    {% for datas, values in values['themes'] if datas == category %}
        {% for value, key in values %}
            <li>
                <img src="{{ asset(key.urllow) }}" class="photo-diapo" id="{{ value }}" {% if loop.first %}data-zoom-image="{{ asset(key.url) }}"{% endif %}/>

                <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>

                <h3 class="photo-titre">{{ key.titre }}</h3>
                <h4 class="photo-date">{{ key.date }}</h4>
                <p class="photo-description">{{ key.description }}</p>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Please note this only modifies the HTML your get from the view, which means that it's up to your JavaScript code and the browser to determine whether this image is the first one. My answer assumes that you take care of that yourself.